# How to use typescript modules w/ browserify?

Tags: typescript, reactjs, browserify

I'm new to typescript and I'm currently using CJS w/ help from browserify. When I added typescript to the mix the TSC compiler complains about require saying

```
error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'require'
```

This is my entry point for browerify

```
var Hello:any = require('hello.js').Hello;
```

here is my hello js file (required above)

```
var React = require('react');

var Hello = React.createClass({displayName: 'Hello',
    render: function() {
        return React.DOM.div(null, "Hello ", this.props.name);
    }
});

exports.Hello = Hello;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexB for his reply. Adding the def to the top of my app.ts like I show below solved this issue

```
///<reference path='../typings/node.d.ts' />

var Hello:any = require('hello.js').Hello;
```

**Update**

It's also worth a mention ... if you don't want/care to have the typing information you can omit it as follows

```
declare var require:any;

var Hello:any = require('hello.js').Hello;
```

Comment: Ah, so I got it half right. It was the node library, not browserify causing trouble. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 7):

You can fix this for any class by making declarations which tell Typescript how to parse an external class.

Fortunately for you, this has already been done for a large number of libraries.

Include this as a reference in your file.

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/browserify