# Handlebars Templates and Browserify with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, require, handlebars.js, browserify

I'm in the process of porting a project to TypeScript.  The project combines Handlebars and Browserify with [hbsfy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/hbsfy) to handle templates.  This means I have JavaScript code like this:

```
var photosTemplate = require('./views/photos.hbs');
```

Which requires in a template file called "photos.hbs" from a views folder which looks a little like this:

```
{{#each this}}
    <span class="title">{{title}}</span>
{{/each}}
```

There's a gulpfile that runs as part of the build step to convert the template into a function that can be used.  This means that in my consuming file I can write code like this which uses the function template:

```
var newHtml = photosTemplate([{title: "test title 1"}, {title: "test title 2"}]);
```

The question is, how can this be made to work for TypeScript?  I've switched my `var` for an `import` and moved to using the `--module commonjs` compiler flag:

```
import photosTemplate = require('./views/photos.hbs');
```

At this point I encounter the error:

> error TS2307: Cannot find external module './views/photos.hbs'.

Fair enough you might think.  So I created a `photos.hbs.d.ts` to sit alongside that looks like this:

```
interface photos {
    (context: any, options?: any): string;
}

export = photos;
```

This is a simple interface that illustrates how the photos template is being used.  However, with this in place the compiler yields the error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'photosTemplate'.

There's a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23957928/761388  I think the problem is my `photos.hbs.d.ts` file but I'm not sure what's wrong with it.  I feel like I'm missing something very simple in the definition to do with external modules.  But for the life of me I can't work out what it is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me...

photos.hbs.d.ts

```
declare function photos (context: any, options?: any): string;

export = photos;
```

Using it:

```
import photosTemplate = require('./views/photos.hbs');

photosTemplate("");
```

The reason being you want to actually *call* the function, not just define a signature.

You could also do:

```
interface Photos {
    (context: any, options?: any): string;
}

declare var photos: Photos;

export = photos;
```

Comment: And that Steve is why I like you :-)  You know that feeling when you've been looking at something too long and you can't fix the problem and just need to walk away and come back later?  That.  Entirely.  Thanks mate!